# Import remote postgresql database via ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, postgresql, database-administration, bash

I have two machines:

- `Remote`, Ubuntu server, example.com, database: `staging` (owner user2, pass2), passwordless login for user1 (sudoer) via ssh
- `Local`, Ubuntu, localhost, database: `local` (owner user3, pass3)

The question is:

- How to import data and structure of `staging` database to `local` (and vice versa) in one command/script?
- How to set up the permissions?

These are not production databases, so I don't need real time sync. I just need to automate the `psql` tasks (usually done by go to phppgadmin, export the data to file, import the data from file via `psql`, all from `Local` machine).

The best solution would be database owner/password independent, because I have few pairs more of such a databases. I have a root access on both machines and I can install any additional required users accounts/software.

Comment: Either use the new replication features in 9.x or perform regular backup from production and restore to your staging server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be simple enough as just scripting the database dumping and then transferring the file to the other database server and then restoring:

The 'pg_dump' utility found with the PostgreSQL Server can be utilized by Database Administrators for taking dumps or backups of databases into a file. The syntax of pg_dump is :

## pg_dump databasename -f outputfile -i -x -O -R -S username

I am not a fan completely of this script http://www.wisdombay.com/articles/pg_dmp.sh  but it should work just fine for you.

The reason for my caution is - because it houses your login/passwords

Now simply scp to the backup server and run a cron job to import the databases.

If stuck - let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this script before, but I think plain text passwords are not a good solution at all. Maybe some setup in sudoers file to run this script is needed. But I think, when I already have a passwordless access with ssh, I might run some commands just as a parameter for ssh. But what commands? ;)

Comment: Use .pgpass to store your password, that's safe. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html